# Does Mercurial make backups of changes?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, content-management-system

Kind of an elementary question, but I'm having trouble grasping the Mercurial SCM program. I understand it's used for tracking changes to files, but is that the extent of it. I skimmed through the man pages and the content on their tutorial pages, but it seemed to only talk about how detailed you can be with the tracking. What else?

Just to be clear, I can see why it's important to track these changes, but in addition to that, wouldn't it be beneficial to have the ability to revert back to an older state? Pardon my ignorance, beginner developer here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly that. In Mercurial's case look at [`update`](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) to switch to any changeset in the history of your repository. This can let you look at earlier versions of the project but I think a more common case is using it to maintain multiple branches of work at once: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide#separate_features

Comment: Thank you @Jonah, I will give the use-cases another look through! But I tried the `update` command and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'd even phrase that more strongly: It's the purpose of a VCM to be able to access any older version as well as analyse the changes between versions. However mind: those are NOT backups; internally it's most often stored as deltas compared to previous versions, thus you can easily corrupt many revisions at once when tampering with data in .hg